# Matching columns in two dataframes given a condition on column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. E.g.:

```
df1 <- data.frame(actor = c("Angel","David","Adah","Sophia"),
                  gender=c("Unknown","male","Unknown","female"),
                  others= c("some","other","info","a"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   actor    gender   others
1  Angel    Unknown  some
2  David    Male     other
3  Adah     Unknown  info
4  Sophia   female   a

df2 <- data.frame(names = c("Miguel","Angel","David","Sophia"),
                  gender=c("male","male","male","female"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   names    gender
1  Miguel   male
2  Angel    male
3  David    male
4  Sophia   female
```

And I want to complete the "Unknown" genders in the df1 with the df2.
I tried doing:

```
df1$gender[df1$gender == "Unknown"] <- df2$gender[ df2$names %in% df1$actor[df1$gender == "Unknown"]]
```

But the result was not in the correct order, even though the number of male or female was correct.

So the result I want is:

```
   actor    gender           others
1  Angel    male             some
2  David    male             other
3  Adah     Unknown (or NA)  info
4  Sophia   female           a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completing missing data is a good use case for `dplyr::coalesce`. In this scenario it is not strictly necessary, but if you had multiple tables with incomplete information it can come in handy!

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- 
  data.frame(
    actor  = c("Angel","David","Adah","Sophia"),
    gender =c("Unknown","male","Unknown","female"),
    others = c("some","other","info","a"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

df2 <- 
  data.frame(
    names  = c("Miguel","Angel","David","Sophia"),
    gender = c("male","male","male","female"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# Fix encoding of "Unknown" to NA
df1$gender[df1$gender == 'Unknown']  <- NA

# Perform a left join by matching actor to names
# then coalesce the gender columns with preference for
# gender from df1.
# Then select your desired columns
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('actor' = 'names')) %>%
  mutate(gender = coalesce(gender.x, gender.y)) %>%
  select(actor, gender, others)

#    actor gender others
# 1  Angel   male   some
# 2  David   male  other
# 3   Adah   <NA>   info
# 4 Sophia female      a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The coalesce function is the key to my problems!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a left join `merge` of the two data frames with an `ifelse` to update *gender*, followed by a re-order of rows. Specifically, a key is added to first data frame as helper column to order after `merge`.

```
# MERGE AFTER ADD key COLUMN TO df1 AND RENAME COLUMNS IN df2
mdf <- merge(transform(df1, key=seq(nrow(df1))), setNames(df2, c('actor','gender')),
             by='actor', all.x=TRUE, suffixes=c('','_'))
mdf$gender <- ifelse(is.na(mdf$gender_), mdf$gender, mdf$gender_)

# RE-ORDER ROWS BY, THEN REMOVE HELPER COLUMNS
mdf <- with(mdf, transform(mdf[order(key),], key=NULL, gender_=NULL))
row.names(mdf) <- NULL

mdf
#    actor  gender others
# 1  Angel    male   some
# 2  David    male  other
# 3   Adah Unknown   info
# 4 Sophia  female      a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first part is working, but the Re-ordering is not working for me, not sure why.

Comment: Can you confirm the posted data is exactly like your actual data? What happens instead -rows are just unordered? Any errors?

Comment: The dataset is much bigger, but I think the format is mainly what I posted. The error says that the number of rows does not match when trying to transform.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `safe_left_join` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), 
and resolve column conflicts using coalesce

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

df1$gender[df1$gender == "Unknown"] <- NA
safe_left_join(df1, df2, by = c(actor = "names"), conflict = coalesce)
#    actor gender others
# 1  Angel   male   some
# 2  David   male  other
# 3   Adah   <NA>   info
# 4 Sophia female      a
```